# Insert different fontset icons next to header in angular tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs, icons, angular-ui

I have 4 different tabs made with angular tabs. I want to put a matching icon next to each header text in the tabs. Any idea on how this is possible?(new at angular) So far, I've only managed to statically push the same icon out 4 times, instead of different icons on each tab. I haven't found any solution from other posts yet. If I've overseen one, let me know.

My angular:

```
$scope.tabs = [
        { title: 'Mobilnumre', selected: function () { $scope.showAllSubscriptions(); } },
        { title: 'Medarbejdernumre', selected: function () { $scope.showEmployeeSubscriptions(); } },
        { title: 'Hovednumre', selected: function () { $scope.showPrimarySubscriptions(); } },
        { title: 'Mobilt Bredbånd', selected: function () { $scope.showDataSubscriptions(); } },
    ];
```

My Html:

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
        <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="tab.selected()">
            <tab-heading ng-repeat=""></tab-heading>
            <div ng-include="'MobileSubscriptionTable'"></div>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can add another property for icon name inside your array

```
$scope.tabs = [
        { title: 'Mobilnumre', selected: function () { $scope.showAllSubscriptions(); icon :'NameOfIcon'} },
    ];
```

and bind that icon from ng-repeat.

Comment: I shoule maybe mention that it's icon from icomoon. Coming from CSS. Not sure if it has anything to say? The icon is basically just a CSS class.

Comment: Tried your solution, I can't make it work. It just prints the icon as a string, flat html.

Comment: basically you have to use it where your are putting hardcoded one.